# newly installed picture window bends under pressure

Tags: windows, retrofit

We have just got new retrofit windows installed yesterday, argon two pane vinyl windows, Alside brand. They have lots of smudges all over so I started cleaning them. The biggest of them, tempered picture window on the porch feels somewhat flimsy. I press the rag against it and it moves, bends and come back after I release the pressure.
Is that normal?

The contractor claims it is normal but the old window ( *original wooden single pane* ) was certainly not moving. Also, none of the other windows ( *some of them also big picture windows although none of them this big* ) are doing it.

Other question is about the smudges, some seem to be caulk, some glue-ish and some oil. I can also see a big Alside sign in the top part under a certain angle. None of it comes off easily with the Windex. The oily patches not at all. The contractor recommended to clean it with lacquer thinner. Is that okay? something like acetone? Is not it going to damage the layer on the window?

Comment: If there is not a film on the window then Acetone should work, i use denatured alcohol. Get the bulk of the caulk or stickers off with a razor blade scraper and then use the acetone. "*Is not it going to damage the layer on the window*" do you know if there is a film on the glass ?

Comment: @AlaskaMan thank you! I do not know if there is a film. Does not look like to me. it feels just like glass. However, the windows appear to be darker from the outside and completely clear from the inside so I thought there must be some layering

Answer (score 2):

Each window manufacturer has an engineering department that can help you calculate the maximum size for your particular location.

Each region in the U.S. has a wind load requirement. Based on that wind load, each brand of window and each series (style of window) can only support a maximum window size.

Here’s their customer service info:

https://www.alside.com/support/contact-us/

I’d call and ask for their engineering department and be prepared to give them the overall size, style (brand series, like 1700 Series, etc.) and number of panes. They can quickly tell you the maximum size allowed in your geographical location.

Remember, it’s important to get this right or you’ll void the warranty. BTW, if it’s oversized, I’d ask for a refund from the installer. The engineering department can email you the maximum size in order to not void the warranty that you can show the installer.